Example of an infinite dimensional $C^{\ast}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ whose dual space $\mathcal{A}^{\ast}$ is an injective Banach space.
A Banach space  $X$ is called injective if, for any Banach space $ Y$ and any bounded linear operator $T: Y \to X $, $T$ can be extended to a larger space containing $ Y $ as a closed subspace.
I am looking for an example of an infinite dimensional $C^{\ast}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ whose dual space $\mathcal{A}^{\ast}$ is an injective Banach space?
Can someone please tell how to think about this example?

There's no such $\mathcal{A}$. Indeed, if $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite-dimensional and $\mathcal{A}^\ast$ is injective, then by Proposition 1.15 here, $\mathcal{A}^\ast$ must contain a subspace isomorphic to $\ell^\infty$. Let $\pi: \ell^\infty \to \mathcal{A}^\ast$ be the inclusion map. By Hahn-Banach, there exists a left inverse $\phi: \mathcal{A}^\ast \to \ell^\infty$ of $\pi$, i.e., $\phi \circ \pi = \text{Id}_{\ell^\infty}$. On the other hand, by a result of Haagerup, $\pi$ must factor through a Hilbert space, whence $\text{Id}_{\ell^\infty} = \phi \circ \pi$ must factor through a Hilbert space as well, i.e., $\text{Id}_{\ell^\infty} = P \circ Q$ for some $Q: \ell^\infty \to H$, $P: H \to \ell^\infty$, $H$ Hilbert space. This is, however, not possible, as this would imply $Q$ is bounded below, whence $Q(\ell^\infty)$ is a closed subspace of $H$ isomorphic to $\ell^\infty$, so $\ell^\infty$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space, which is not true.
